# C/C++ single format specifier to print 0.0, 1.0, 0.025

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, format-specifiers

What single format string can be used to print 0.0, 1.0, 0.025 ? eg given:

```
float vals[3] = { 0.0f, 1f, 0.025f };

for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%g\n", vals[i]);
```

desired output:

```
0.0
1.0
0.025
```

but instead get:

```
0
1
0.025
```

Have tried various width specifiers and %f vs %g but can't get what I want.

If there's a c++ alternative that's fine to.

Comment: Try `setprecision`. It's in `<iomanip>`, which has the more C++like forms of formatting output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use * to tell printf the precision will come from an int argument value.

```
printf("%.*f\n", (vals[i] == (int)vals[i]) ? 1 : 3 ,vals[i]);
```

should print:

```
0.0
1.0
0.025
```

Comment: close enough, though went with printf("%g%s\n", vals[i], ((vals[i] == (int)vals[i]) ? ".0" : "")); so that I don't lose precision

Comment: `x == nearbyint(x)` checks for integer values, but works for floats outside the INT_MIN .. INT_MAX range.  Out-of-range FP->int conversion has undefined behaviour in C and C++.

Answer (score 4):

You can use setprecision(int n), where n is the number of decimal places to output. Any trailing zeros will not be shown unless you use fixed notation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

float vals[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.025f };
std::cout << setprecision(5);
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
std::cout << vals[i];
```

Output

```
0.0
1.0
0.025
```

Change the following for fixed notation

```
cout << setprecision(5) << fixed;
```

Output

```
0.00000
1.00000
0.02500
```

edit: There is also scientific notation, you can figure out what that does.
      setprecision() ---> std::setprecision()

Comment: You forgot to specify std namespace. (`std::cout`)

Comment: The OP asked for "0.0", "1.0", "0.025". Not "0.00000", "1.00000", "0.02500".

Comment: I showed the format you need in the beginning, the extra part is just an fyi. As long as you don't use fixed notation, you will get the desired result.

Comment: the code you show (setprecision, without fixed) doesn't provide the trailing .0 for me g++ or visual studio compiler

Comment: Without fixed it should print "0" and "1". (also, if you are explicitly using std::, it should be added to setprecision as well)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the precision following the decimal place for floating point numbers and doubles when you print it.  This is done with a format specifier like: %.Nf where N is a positive integer.  So if you used:

```
printf("%.3f\n", vals[i]);
```

Your output is:

```
0.000
1.000
0.025
```

But you can't get it to print it exactly the way you declared it. You would have to change the precision at different stages of the loop (%.1f for the first 2 iterations and then %.3f for the last iteration).
There are a lot of options for printf including leading spaces as well:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

edit:

So if you want to have a minimum of 1 decimal place printed as you explained in your comment you can add an explicit check for that one case:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  float vals[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.025f };

  for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    if( fmod(vals[i],1) == 0) printf("%.1f\n", vals[i]);
    else printf("%f\n", vals[i]);
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
0.0
1.0
0.025000
```

Comment: yep im aware of the various specifiers. just couldn't work out a combination to get what I want. doesn't necessarily need to be 'as declared' just with a minimum of one ".0" . seems odd if it's not possible though...

Comment: A cheaper check (instead of `fmod(x, 1.0)`) would be `x == nearbyint(x)`.